# Why does the trailing slash in ln -s matter?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, symlink

Let's say (hypothetically) that I wanted to make a symlink to my Documents folder on my Desktop. I would do this:

```
cd ~/Desktop
ln -s ~/Documents
```

which will make a symlink called Documents on my Desktop.

However, when I do this (note the trailing slash after `~/Documents`:

```
cd ~/Desktop
ln -s ~/Documents/
```

I get:

```
ln: ./: File exists
```

Howcome? Why does the trailing slash matter in this case, and what does a trailing slash mean in general?

Comment: What the trailing slash means is application-dependent.

Comment: Possible same on Unix: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7769/include-in-symlink-to-a-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the trailing slash is application-dependent. On my system (CentOS 5), both worked fine.

In this case, I'd say that ln is interpreting `~/Documents/` as a path, and using a default filename of `.` to refer to the current directory, for an effective combined path of `~/Documents/.`. Since you're not specifying the name of the destination link, it's picking the one that matches the 'sepecified' filename, `.`, which already exists.

I get a similar error to yours when I specify `~/Documents/.` explicitly.

You can solve this by specifying the name of the link to create explicitly. `ln -s ~/Documents/ Documents` should work for you.